# How many references to Javascript Objects

Tags: javascript, oop, object

Is it possible to know how many references exists to an Object in Javascript?

I have an closure variable which store all instances to retrieve when the same value class is instanced. e.g. If Nit(123) is in memory I return the same reference.

I would like to clean the reference in closure when there is any reference outside to this object anymore.

When there is no other reference except in the closure 'instances' I want it to be cleaned and free to Garbage Collector

```
const Nit = (function(){

    //closure to store instances
    const instances = [];

    class Nit {

        constructor(nit){

            //class have only one property immutable
            //writeble false to make it explicity

            Object.defineProperty(this, 'nit', {
                value: nit,
                writable: false
            });

            //if an instance of this value already exists 
            //return the same reference

            if(!instances[this]){
                instances[this] = this;
                console.log(instances);
            }
            else{
                return instances[this];
            }

    }

    //valueOf garantee instances are comparable 
    //and interchangeable (because are immutable)

    Nit.prototype.valueOf = function(){
        return this.nit;
    };

    return Nit;

})();
```

So, if I instance:

```
var a = new Nit(1234)
```

my closure instances = [ ObjectNit{1234} ]

If i clean this only one reference (a = null) 
I want my closure reference to be cleaned too.

so, my closure instances = [ ]

Comment: Rather than an array, you could use a WeakMap -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakMap

Comment: Keith, I'm trying to understand WeakMap.. but how coud it help me?

Comment: I'm not really sure what your trying to achieve..  `If i clean this only one reference (a = null) I want my closure reference to be cleaned too.`  Could you explain this a bit more.

Comment: When there is no other reference except in the closure 'instances' I want it to be cleaned and free to Garbage Collector

Comment: The week map is storage, that won't stop garbage collector from grabbing variables "inside". It is not iterable due to this fact, try to play with it a bit. It may be the right solution for you